# Boolean operations on Catmull-Clark control surface meshes?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

How would I perform Boolean operations (either directly or as a modifier), not on two (closed) meshes, but on the two Catmull-Clark limit surfaces they represent, such that the result is another Catmull-Clark control surface (with proper edge and vertex crease values) whose Catmull-Clark limit surface is the result of the Boolean operation on the two input limit surfaces.

Comment: As I understand your question, wouldn't that need to apply a reverse catmull-clark algorithm to the resulting boolean shape? I don't think Blender has this ability now. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228968237_Reverse_Catmull-Clark_Subdivision

Comment: Your observation about needing to implement a reverse Catmull-Clark(CC) is only **somewhat** correct. The obvious way to think of the problem is 1) apply the CC, 2) perform the Boolean operation, then 3) apply a reverse CC. This misses two things: The CC **limit surface** is infinitely subdivided, so it can't be represented as an (in memory) mesh, and; Except for the interface curves where the limit surfaces meet, all the control points you need for the resulting mesh **should** already exist in one of the input control meshes. The only reverse CC would be on the interface curves.